# How inactive issuance get's calculated or how do we customize it in substrate-node-template

Tags: substrate-node-template, chainspec

So i was working with substrate-node-template . I can see how total issuance is getting calculated from substrate node template but confused of how would i set up inactive issuance . What are the significance behind inactive issuance . How it get's increased after specific time . How it's related to total issuance ?